# Linking verb followed by a verb

Tags: linking-verbs

According to The British Council [description](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/link-verbs), links-verbs are followed by either a noun or an adjective.

In the following sentence, "**smiling**" is a verb, and as I see it, "**is**" acts as a linking verb.

> "Jane is smiling."

If my assumption is correct, how does it correlate with the definition above? I mean, if we say that links-verbs are followed by either a noun or an adjective, how come we have a verb (smiling) afterward?

Comment: ...because _is_ in your sentence is not a "linking verb". It is a "helping verb" --if you want to use those definitions.

Comment: No: the auxiliary verb "be" has the gerund-participial clause "smiling" as complement. Together, they mark the progressive aspect, which represents a situation in progress.  Predicative "be" is, as you say, generally followed by an NP ("Ed is a teacher") or an AdjP ("Kim is happy").

Comment: What Cascabel said.  See, for example, [Verbs with Helpers](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/verb_tenses/verbs_with_helpers.html)

Comment: For matching coverage at the British Council see https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/verb-phrases -- it's the second form